# jQuery scroll iframe on mobile using animate

Tags: jquery, iframe, mobile, scroll

I have an iframe containing a web page that uses jQuery.

To scroll to a specific position of the iframed page (the .js is included in the iframed page, non in the container page) I use:

**`$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: POSITION}, DURATION);`**

I tested that the scroll works on latest desktop Firefox, Explorer, Safari and Chrome
but on mobile iPad and Android native browser fails (on Firefox mobile it works).

Anyone has some suggestion?

Comment: i feel for your end users... iFrame on a mobile device ?! Two Finger Scrolling should be fun :)

Comment: Unlucky the mobile development was a "not in first revision" request... and the iFrame is needed because the pages are on 2 different domains (and also on 2 different hosting structure) and the container page template has to be kept :(